# how to go to another page on link or button click in ionic 2

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

i want to go to home page when i click on below given link. but its not taking 
me to the page i wanna go. i wanna visit home page when i click on below 
mentioned link or button. Do i have to add any angular code? if yes then 
what i have to write and in which file??

```
      <ion-header>
        <ion-navbar>
          <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
          </button>
          <ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
        </ion-navbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content padding>
        <a href="#/home.html">click to home page</a>
        <button type="button" ng-click="home()">click to home page</button>
      </ion-content>
```

Comment: what is your homepage url in your routing config?

Comment: i have created a page named as "prorile" and the location is "src/pages/profile page and all other page"

Comment: no , I mean the absolute URL for your home page. i.e `http://localhost/homepage`

Answer (score 3):

html file

```
<button ion-button (click)="home()">go to home page</button>
```

.ts file

```
import {HomePage} from '../../pages/home/home';
```

call function home()

```
home(){
this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain where i have to paste these code?? i mean in which files???

Comment: from which page you have to go HomePage, In that page you Add this code  and import HomePage to this page,

Comment: refer this https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Answer (score 0):

in your **html** file,

```
<button type="button" (click)="home()">click to home page</button>
```

in your **ts** file,

```
home(){
 this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
}
```

Don't forget to import **HomePage** in your .ts file!

Comment: can you please explain in which file i have to paste this

"home(){
 this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
}"
 and 

"import {HomePage} from '../../pages/home/home';" this code?

Comment: In which page you have Click to home page button? paste it there

Comment: and  don't forget to import `NavController`